# OOPs : Suggest design for the following scenario

Tags: java, oop

I have a Product object. The Product is taxed at different rates in different places/situations. 
   Some of the products are not taxable at all (Example : Medicine)

For example , buying the product may cost  $X in shop A and $Y at shop B . It can cost differently in two different states(state taxes are different).

My question is , can we have the attributes to determine the taxes inside the Product object itself.

For example is it a good idea to have attributes such as

```
                   Boolean isImported ;
                   Boolean isTaxable ;
```

Or do we have a better design pattern to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I believe there is no single, good answer to this question.

You can have the attributes to determine the taxes inside a `Product`. However, I would recommend to have a separate class (`TaxCalculator`?) that would calculate the tax of a `Product` based on its origin, type, transaction, etc. The motivation is that the `Product` should represent a product data only; why should e.g. a bottle of wine care what are the taxes assigned to it? Something else should do it, something that is specialised in calculating the tax based on the product.

But that is only my opinion and I do not claim it is the best one. I would like to hear from some more experienced users.

Answer (score 2):

Products need not to know about the tax. Tax is logically related to a sale, so is the product price. In our app we have the following (simplified):

```
public class Invoice {
    private InvoiceItem[] invoiceItems;
}

public class InvoiceItem{
    private ProductPrice productPrice;
    private BigDecimal taxRate;
}

public class ProductPrice{
    private Product product;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String currencyCode;
}

public class Product{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly put those attributes in the Product class.

Or you can create a separate interface (`TaxStrategy`?) that would take a `Product` and return a `Money` tax amount:

```
public interface TaxStrategy {
    Money calculateTax(Product p);
}
```

That way you can have different implementations of the interface that compute taxes in different ways.  Products need not know that they're taxable.  It separates the thing that you sell from the way that you price it.

Comment: is it like strategy pattern ?

Comment: The class name I chose is certainly suggesting that.  Does the answer change the way you feel about the suggestion?

Comment: My question is, even if I have an interface like the one you suggested above , I still pass the product , and the product must contain some information about , say , is it imported or is it taxable etc ?

Comment: Maybe; I don't know all the details about your design.  You have a choice about where you put those things.  Each implementation of the interface might do things differently.  What if one shop in one state decides to have a tax amnesty just for one day?  This design will accomodate it.  Your example of a state-dependent tax suggests a map with state as key and tax implementation as value.  Look it up and go.